# Should I consider following code as thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have following POCO class.

```
public class SessionInfo 
{
   public int UserID { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Role> UserRoles { get; set; }
   public List<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

and `SessionService` class as below:

```
public static class SessionService
{
    static string userName;
    static int userID;
    static List<Role> RoleList;

    public static SessionInfo SetServiceSession<T>(T service) where T : class
    {
        SessionInfo sessionInfo;
        SetApiControllerSessionValue();
        sessionInfo = new SessionInfo { UserID = userID, UserName = userName, UserRoles = RoleList, Name = null, Permissions = null };
        //above statement fills the value set by SetApiControllerSessionValue into the sessionInfo object and returns.
        return sessionInfo;
    }

    private static void SetApiControllerSessionValue()
    {
        .....
        .....
        //Here is some logic that sets the static member `userName`, `userId` and `RoleList` of `SessionService` class
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

Now I am calling `SetServiceSession` method from every action of every api controller like below:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{

    public List<TestPOCO> Get()
    {
        .....
        .....
        TestService service = new TestService(uow);
        SessionInfo = SessionService.SetManagerSession<TestService>(service);
        .....
        .....
        .....
    }

    .....
    .....
    // Same way for post, create and delete.
    .....        
    .....

}
```

Now if server is processing simultaneously two request let's say Get and Post for two different session, `SessionService.SetManagerSession` will be executed in parallel. So question is can it be resulted in invalid session Values (exchanged static values in two requests) as it is being executed in parallel? If yes what is the solution for that?

Also correct me if my understanding about above code is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A static class with a static property holding a `userID` property, certainly not thread safe and a security risk.

Comment: @DavidG hmm.. so my doubt turns true. Can you suggest me possible solution in such a case?

Comment: Don't use a static class or pass in all the required values it needs as parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I consider following code as thread safe?

No, obviously not. If `SetServiceSession` is concurrently in multiple threads, `userName`, `userID` etc fields will be messed up.

> If yes what is the solution for that?

There are only two options.

1. Don't use a shared state.
2. Use proper synchronization.

I prefer option 1. In this case you can completely get rid of that static members and make the `SetApiControllerSessionValue` to return a `SessionInfo`. Of course, rename the method as `GetApiControllerSessionValue`.

```
public static SessionInfo SetServiceSession<T>(T service) where T : class
{
    SessionInfo sessionInfo = GetApiControllerSessionValue();
    //Do something with sessionInfo, if needed
    return sessionInfo;
}

private static SessionInfo GetApiControllerSessionValue()
{
    //Get SessionInfo here.
    //If you need to access any other shared state here, you must need synchronization.
}
```

For more information about synchronization primitives [refer this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you want me to provide a specific answer than a generic one as above, post your original code.